# "'@param' is redundant in TypeScript code if it has no description." TSLint error?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application, angular8

I have an Angular 8 project and I run `ng lint`.

Even though I have a `@description` decorator associated with a particular method, TSLint complains and says: `"'@param' is redundant in TypeScript code if it has no description."` in various places in my code.

For example, the aforementioned error would show when a method is written like this (TypeScript):

```
  /**
   * @description my lovely description
   * @param empDetails
  */
  getHeaderBasedonEmpDetails(empDetails: EmployeeDetails) {
    if (someVar) {
      return 'yeah'
    } else {
      return 'nah'
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "common-logger-angular": "^1.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/karma-viewport": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-webdriver-launcher": "^1.0.5",
    "lighthouse": "^5.1.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.2.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.14.2",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tslint.json (relevant (in root)):

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "completed-docs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

tslint.json (relevant (in /src)):

```
{
  "extends": "../tslint.json",
  "rules": {
    "completed-docs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

I have tried:

- As shown in the tslint files, manually disabling the `completed-docs` rule.
- Adding `/* tslint:disable:completed-docs */` to the top of the file where TSLint is complaining
- Removing `@description` decorator and leaving it as just a comment

What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I believe what that error is saying is that the `@param` needs a description, not that you need a `@description` tag. For example `@param empDetails The employee details.` includes a param description. You could also just delete the `@param` line, as this isn't useful in TypeScript (unless it provides some human readable description, ie what the error says).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add some small description behind `empDetails`

```
  /**
   * @description my lovely description
   * @param empDetails contain employee details
  */
```